# Java executorService delay

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executor

I have 2 threads and I need to run them as thead pool and the delay between each of them runs is 10 secs.

As far I understand, I should do something like this

```
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(firstThread, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture2 = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(secondThread, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    try {
        scheduledFuture.get();
        scheduledFuture2.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

By the way, I am not sure that this is "best practice". I would be happy to get appropriate implementation.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem here... assuming that the code runs correctly, is there any other concern you have?

Comment: i need to do that once, but this is looks like a loop

Comment: In that case, simply use `schedule()`? See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: Because with what you did in your code, `scheduleAtFixedRate(R, x, y, TU)` means "run R after a delay of x, then afterward repeatedly run R after a delay of y".

Comment: Next time, please mention in the question what went wrong =)

Comment: @Nayuki, Since your comment is solution to the problem, can you please post it as answer?

Comment: @nayuki, yeap, i will do that!